# jQuery Tag-It! - How to change border on focus

Tags: jquery, css, tag-it

I'm using [jQuery Tag-It!](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/) in my project. 
I want to make my object's border visible when the `onfocus` event fires, but I can't make it work.

My code:

```
<ul id="TagsDesc" name="nameOfSelect" runat="server" ></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#<%=TagsDesc.ClientID %>').focus(function () {
         $(this).css("border", "1px solid");
      });

      $('#<%=TagsDesc.ClientID %>').tagit({ 
        'maxTags': 10,'minLength': 1,
        'maxLength': 12,
        'tagsChanged': showTags
      });

      function showTags() {
         var tags = $('#<%=TagsDesc.ClientID %>').tagit("tags");
         var tagsContainer = $('#<%=tagsContainer.ClientID %>');
         var res = '';
         for (var i in tags)
            res += ',' + tags[i].value;
         tagsContainer.val(res);
      }
   });
</script>
```

Any idea please?

Comment: If your site is live, please provide a link to it, or make a demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: there is a missing of closing script tag..

Comment: no that's just a writing mistake

Comment: @Abody97 How can i do a demo on jsFiddle i don't know .. i never used the site

Comment: what is `$('#<%=TagsDesc.ClientID %>')`, is it a focusable element like `input` `textarea` or so?

Comment: it's an ASP.net project that's how you call an element by it's client id

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The focus event is actually applicable to focusable elements only. (`<input>`, `<select>`, etc.)

`ul` or `li` are not focusable by default.

> The focus event is sent to an element when it gains focus. This event
>   is implicitly applicable to a limited set of elements, such as form
>   elements (`<input>`, `<select>`, etc.) and links (`<a href>`). In recent
>   browser versions, the event can be extended to include all element
>   types by explicitly setting the element's tabindex property. An
>   element can gain focus via keyboard commands, such as the Tab key, or
>   by mouse clicks on the element.

One work around is to use `tabidex` on the element you want to make focusable, not sure if its completely cross browser. Adding a `tabindex` makes most elements focusable as it forces to be focused by keboard.

For setting css values you can use `:focus` pseudo seleector rather than using jquery.

```
.focusableelement:focus{
  border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

## Specific answer for tagit:

apply `focus` event on input with class `ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete-input` and change border of the parent element with classes `tagit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all`

Answer (score 1):

You have to attach event handlers on the input field created by tag-it. It's a bit of a DOM traversing hassle, but this worked for me using jQuery 1.11 and tag-it 2.0:

```
  $("#selector")
    .tagit({
       // whatever you need
    })
    // bind events on tag-it's input field 
    .siblings("ul.tagit")
    .first()
    .find("input:first")
    .on("focus", function() {
      $(this).closest("ul.tagit").addClass("focus");
    })
    .on("blur", function() {
      $(this).closest("ul.tagit").removeClass("focus");
    });
```

Now add appropriate CSS rules in your stylesheet:

```
ul.tagit.focus {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```